# bpy: Show a blender popup_menu that waits until an external function returns and shows a spinner until then

Tags: python, interface, operator

I'm trying to write a script that shows a text information to a user while waiting for another process to finish. Ideally this also shows some kind of spinner, to show that it's still alive. I need this in my application since some of my functions are accessing external data via network, which can potentially take quite some time. I do need the user to wait for this process to finish (fire&forget is not an option).

My approach is to use a popup_menu, the threading module and a modal operator. The idea is to start longexternalfunction in a separate thread and while waiting for it to return, keep the user in the modal operator. The operator starts a second thread that generates a simple ascii spinner text and shows that text in the popup menu. I would imagine such a ui element to be quite useful in a number of cases if blocking processes potentially take some time to complete.

I found some examples to show function progress with the mouse cursor - which is a valid alternative for me, if this does not work, and looked into modal operators in general to come up with the code below. While I came quite a way I still have some issues though, that defy my understanding of blender ui programming (see also 'FIXME' tags in the code; code is running in 2.82 but with issues):

1. Biggest issue: I don't know how to update the text in the popup menu with the textspinner output
2. The textspinner runs longer than longexternalprocess of course, and I don't know how to stop the thread properly. Currently I get an error when the operator exits, event though I try to use `__del__` to stop the spinner thread with a signal.
3. I guess there are some other (minor?) issues in my code, e.g. declaring and using class variables is not obvious to me in this context (bpy.props.Property... becomes an instance var?)

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent
import threading
import time

def sleeper():
    ''' a long external process '''
    duration = 5.0
    steps = 10
    for i in range(steps):
        slpstep = duration / float(steps)
        time.sleep(slpstep)
        print('sleeping for: {}'.format(slpstep*i))


class My_OT_Info_progress(bpy.types.Operator):
    ''' Display text information in a popup on the screen, wait until process is finished '''
    # See here:
    # https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html
    # https://blenderartists.org/t/showing-progress-of-your-script-running/647230/9

    bl_idname = "my.info_progress"
    bl_label = "Info window with progress"

    # define some vars...
    info_text : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="InfoText", description="Info text for popup")
    icon : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="INFO", description="Icon for popup Info")
    stop_spinner : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="stop_spinner")

    def __init__(self):
        self.spin = threading.Thread(target=self.textspinner)
        self.stop_spinner = False
        print("Init Start")

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop_spinner = True # stop spinner before we exit
        self.spin.join() # FIXME: throws after first run: AttributeError: 'My_OT_Info_progress' object has no attribute 'spin'??
        print("Clean up - End")

    def textspinner(self):
        ''' simple text spinner'''
        wait = 0.1 # duration between updates s
        timeout = 30 # max duration s
        for i in range (int(timeout/wait)):
            if self.stop_spinner: break # FIXME: throws on exit: ReferenceError: StructRNA of type My_OT_Info_progress has been removed
            self.info_text = 'Text{}'.format('.' * int(i%5))
            print(self.info_text)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def execute(self, context):
        # FIXME: where should the code for the popup live? How do I update the info_text attribute of the draw function?
        #self.report({'INFO'}, info_text)
        info_text=self.info_text

        def draw(self,context):
            self.layout.label(text=info_text)    

        bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title="Info", icon='ERROR')
        print('exec')
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        print('modal start')
        while self.func.is_alive(): # while the long external process is running
            return{'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        ''' this is executed when called by a user of with 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' '''

        # start a long external process as separate thread
        self.func = threading.Thread(target=sleeper)
        self.func.start()

        # start a spinner as separate thread
        self.spin.start()

        self.execute(context)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


bpy.utils.register_class(My_OT_Info_progress)
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this! Appreciate pointers in the right direction - even if its only to tell me this is not the way to go about it ;)